# Implementing tqdm using only standard python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

i created some basic implementation of tqdm. The main goal is to have time estimation features using only standard python library.

```py
def tqdm(iterable):
    steps = 0
    init_time = time()
    total_steps = len(iterable)
    last_update = init_time
    for i in iterable:
        yield i
        steps += 1
        if time() - last_update > 0.1:
            last_update = time()
            time_passed = last_update - init_time
            progress = steps / total_steps
            estimated_time = time_passed / progress - time_passed
            estimated_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(estimated_time))
            print(f'\rEST: {estimated_time}', end='')
```

Benchmark is original tqdm module. My tqdm version works a bit worse. Sometimes it shows a bit more estimated time than original tqdm. Do you have any ideas how to improve my code and make it more robust like original tqdm module?

Comment: The only way to make it behave like tqdm is to look at the source code of tqdm

Comment: @Marco Bonelli yup, i know, but there is another goal: code has to be as easy and small as it can be, however tqdm uses complex logic to calculate est time and show any other statistic. Do you see any bugs in my implementation?

Comment: The code above estimates the finish time based on the average time per completed iteration. This average time is `time_passed / number_completed_iteration`.  tqdm uses instead a weighted average: in its computations the speed of the most recent iterations has a bigger weight than the speed of more distant ones.